# Stomp::readFrame() function is very slow working?

Tags: php, performance, activemq-classic, stomp

I am using ActiveMQ with PHP. `$stomp->readFrame()` function slowly working How can fix it? I tried other languages like Java, Nodejs etc.. but they are perfect working in same connection properties. I have just a problem in php.

```
try {
  $url = 'tcp://'.$host.":".$port;
  $stomp = new Stomp($url, $user, $password);
  $stomp->subscribe($destination);

  $start = now();
  $count = 0;
  echo "Waiting for messages...\n";
  while(true) {
    $frame = $stomp->readFrame();
    if( $frame ) {
        echo json_decode($frame->body)->Heading;
    }
  }

} catch(StompException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP script outputs only if the content is complete, you can overcome this with `ob_flush()` after the echo.

Comment: I tried, it is not working. I running  php file in CLI platform